# Creating a batch command

Tags: batch-file, command

Say if I type

```
mybatchfile hello
```

It would output: "hello"

The code inside would look something like this:

```
@echo off
echo %fileinputvalue%
```

"%fileinputvalue%" is the input value like "hello"

```
mybatchfile hi
```

It would output: "hi"
I couldn't find an answer so this could be impossible.

Comment: So you need a prim batch which translates the input `hi` to the output `hello` ;-)

Comment: What about [edit]ing your question and correcting the typos rather than commenting?

Comment: You should bookmark [SS64's CMD.EXE reference](http://ss64.com/nt/) as a general reference for Windows batch language. For this particular issue, [the SS64 page on Parameters and Arguments](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) will be of special interest.

Comment: @LotPings Sorry for the 2 typos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your batch file should read

```
@echo off
echo %1
```

Where `%1` means "the first parameter from the command-line" (%1..%9 are directly available; %0 is the batchfile name, you can lose the first parameter by using `shift` [so that the original 10th now becomes `%9`])

I believe that's what you want - it's hard to tell :(

Comment: or use `%*` for "all parameters", making `mybatchfile hello my friend` possible.

Comment: Let me try it :)